# PGAdmin 4 v4 doesn't render correctly in my browser

Tags: google-chrome, pgadmin

I've installed PGAdmin 4 v4 but when I try to launch it, the Google Chrome tab open but the page is not formatted as the following image:

[image: PGAdmin overview]

How can I show correctly this administrative page?

Comment: Did you follow the pre-requisite steps here? https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/server_deployment.html#requirements

Comment: I've tried to follow the guide steps but the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your browser is ignoring style sheet and styles not rendered in the  DOM, this can easily be resolved through your Registry editor,and reset the value of `"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.css\Content Type"` to `"text/css"`
Please read from their thread for further information, from https://www.pgadmin.org/faq/#6